# HSQLDB - invalid authorization specification

Tags: hsqldb

I need help with an issue during the database connection via JPA/Hibernate on hsqldb-2.2.8:

`[AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - invalid authorization specification - not found: manasouza`

I created some user (manasouza) with some password as:

`CREATE USER manasouza PASSWORD 123 ADMIN`

I'm using SQLWorkbench as my database visualizer, and with it I can log on normally. 
Using JPA/Hibernate I already tried the username on uppercase and the password as '123' or as the value cryptographed showed on the PASSWORD_DIGEST column at SYSTEM_USERS database table, but had no success at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `CREATE USER manasouza PASSWORD 123 ADMIN`, HSQLDB 2.2.8 throws an exception. Therefore you must have used a different password.

The user name is converted to all uppercase because it is not double quoted. For the password, you should use single quotes around the string. If you define the password without the single quotes, it must start with a letter and is converted to all uppercase. Therefore if you want the exact case, use `CREATE USER "manasouza" PASSWORD '123' ADMIN`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @fredt. I've done that but no success yet. I figured out something and changed by URL from `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql//localhost` to `jdbc:hsqldb:file:test//localhost`. With this, the user authentication problem was solved. Then I create my tables and sequences again for this database kept on `file:test`, but now the system complains about finding the tables, although my JPA mapping is right: `ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - user lacks privilege or object not found: GFMA_MANUFACTURER` where GFMA_MANUFACTURER is one of my tables...

Comment: Your URLs are not correct. The first one is for a server and should be `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost`. The second one is for an in-process file database and should be: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:test;shutdown=true`. See the Guide about server and in-process databases.

Comment: Ok...thanks again. Now it's clear for me the difference between server connection and file conncection. The question now is why the server connection doesn't authorize my user and the in-process file database does...

Comment: I decided to remake all my database configurations and it seems to work fine now. It must have been some confusion I made on the beginning. I'm using server DB...Thanks for your help