# Connecting to HSQL DB from Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, hsqldb

I start HSQL DB with a Maven plugin (I use the DB in integration tests):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.btmatthews.maven.plugins.inmemdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>inmemdb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <monitorKey>inmemdb</monitorKey>
        <monitorPort>11527</monitorPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
                <type>hsqldb</type>
                <database>MY_DB</database>
                <username>user1</username>
                <password>111</password>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When the DB is up and running I am able to create a JDBC connection:

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/MY_DB", "sa", "");
System.out.print(connection);
```

This code prints: `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@2d22efc3`.

However, when I try to use the same connection settings to configure a data source in Spring, I get an exception (`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/MY_DB" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

I also tried `username`:`user1` and `password`:`111`, it produces another exception: `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid authorization specification - not found: user1`.

How can I connect to this DB from Spring?

Comment: How exactly are you doing in spring? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: are you starting the database with Spring by any chance? Maybe it's not up already.

Comment: @Darshan In the Spring config, I declare the data source that I provided in my question. Then I declare a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` which reference the data source. These beans throw the exception when Spring tries to create them.

Comment: @Stéphane I do not start the DB with Spring, I start it with Maven. I know that Spring has built-in support for in-memory DBs, but I do not want to use it. I think that the DB is up, otherwise I probably would not be able to create a JDBC connection. I can also see that the DB is up in the Maven log.

Comment: @Alex Please provide full stacktrace.

Comment: You start HsqlDB in maven with a username/password and in your app use a different username/password. Obviously that will result in connection refused as soon as you start using it (which is what hibernate is doing during startup, hence the exception).

Comment: @Deinum, at the end of my question, I mentioned that I have tried `user1`/`111` credentials as well. I use `sa` with no password because I can create a JDBC connection with these credentials. I cannot create it with `user1`/`111` for some reason. It looks strange to me too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729107/hsqldb-invalid-authorization-specification for guidance.

Comment: @user3360944 Thank you. I tried a password that starts from a letter; I also tried all-uppercase login and password. When I try to create a JDBC connection manually I still get the same exception: `invalid authorization specification - not found: USER1`.

Comment: @Darshan I have posted the stack trace.

Comment: @Alex you would probably need `JDBCTemplate` to hold you datasource.

Comment: @Darshan My Spring configuration works fine with MySQL. So, I think the problem is in HSQL DB or in my connection settings.

Comment: @Alex your configurations look fine.

Comment: I would conclude that your hsql database is not up when you are trying to connect to from spring.

Comment: @user3360944 You are right! I put the Maven plugin that starts an embedded Tomcat and deploys my web application before the plugin that starts the embedded DB. The application tried to connect to the DB that had not been started yet. I would accept your last comment if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the advice of counsel, I am adding as answer that your hsql db was not running when you tried to connect from Spring.

Comment: Thanks! I put the Maven plugin that starts an embedded Tomcat and deploys my web application before the plugin that starts the embedded DB. The application tried to connect to the DB that had not been started yet.